# How do I get camera to connect to anyone's phone and let the phone take picture using the camera and get that picture back?

Tags: pi-2

I have an idea but not sure if I can Raspberry Pi to do this.

So I have this camera in public that anyone can use. Anyone can connect to the camera using their phone and take picture with it, and get that photo sent back to her phone.

How do I implement this idea, perhaps with a PI?

Comment: the title of your post is asking how to hack people's phones .... i think that you may want to change the title

Comment: How does your phone connects to the camera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing projects that affect the public, be very careful about protecting privacy. For example, the problem statement requires "photo sent back to her phone", which implies that she divulge her phone number to your project. Ick. Stalker cam. But there's another way that might help you interact with the public.

A less invasive way of providing "you are here" feedback would be to use the Pi to take a picture and upload that to a website that they can view on their phone. You can show your website right next to the camera and print the URL for all to see. This protects the privacy of their phone while engaging them to interact with your camera.